# How to create a class without duplicating code?

Tags: c#, inheritance

I have a class Monster

```
class Monster
{
 move()
 attack()
}
```

using inheritance we could create:

```
melee monster : monster
overr attack()

ranged monster : monster
ovverr attack()

flying monster : monster 
overr move()

swimming monster : monster 
overr move()
```

How to create FlyingRangeMonster and MeleeSwimmingMonster without duplicating code?
I suppose we should abandon inheritance and use composition. How to realizate it in this case ?

Thank you!

Comment: Which is the duplicated code here?

Comment: I need to create FlyingRangedMonster and MeleeSwimmingMonster classes, for example if  FlyingRangeMonster : RangedMonster then there will be same code in Move() method in FlyingRangeMonster and FlyingMonster

Comment: Look up Entity Component System

Answer (score 0):

You should create some methods to evaluate move or attack. If you need new monster class with the same move ability, you just override `move` or `attack` to those methods.

So for every type of monster you have one class and overridden methods, I don't see this as duplicated code.

What you are probably intending is inherit class from two classes, but it is not allowed in C# (I think it is possible in C++).

What I would do is create two interfaces, one for moving monsters and one for attacking monsters. You still need implement methods in you monster classes, but you can combine them as you wish. Also you can easily identify if your monster implements moving or attacking interface (or both) - `if (myMonster is IMovingMonster) ...`.

You also can inherit from class and interface, so MeleeSwimmingMonster can by inherited from MeleeMonster and moving interface (or SwimmingMonster and attacking interface). For `public class MeleeSwimmingMonster : MeleeMonster, IMovingMonster` there you don't need to override `attack()` method, if it is same as in MeleeMonster class.

And if you want new ability (singing), you just create new singing interface and you can create new type of singing monsters. So your `public class MeleeSwimmingSingingMonster : MeleeSwimmingMonster, ISingingMonster` can do same moves and attacks as MeleeSwimmingMonster, but you can learn it some song!